# What was the meaning of the name "Allah" before Islam?

Tags: allah

What does the name of Allah mean in the eyes of the Arabs before Islam? (Given that the name of the father of the Prophet of Islam was Abdullah)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pagans of Mecca believed in "Allah" as the head of their pantheon and the creator god, with other deities ascribed as his children.

Islamic history states this was because the Arabs were originally monotheists, being the descendants of [Abraham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham) through [Ishmael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishmael) and followed Abraham's religion of aniconic monotheism ... though over the ages corruptions such as polytheism and idolatry crept in.

Abraham and Ishmael built the Kaabah in Mecca and Ishmael and his progeny settled there, and the Quraysh and other Arabian tribes claimed descent from him.

> [Quran 2:127-129](https://quran.com/2/127-129) And [mention] when **Abraham was raising the foundations of the House and [with him] Ishmael**, [saying], "Our Lord, accept [this] from us. Indeed You are the Hearing, the Knowing. Our Lord, and make us Muslims [in submission] to You and **from our descendants a Muslim nation** [in submission] to You. And show us our rites and accept our repentance. Indeed, You are the Accepting of repentance, the Merciful. Our Lord, and s**end among them a messenger from themselves** who will recite to them Your verses and teach them the Book and wisdom and purify them. Indeed, You are the Exalted in Might, the Wise."
>
> [Quran 14:35-37](https://quran.com/14/35-37) And [mention, O Muhammad], when Abraham said, "My Lord, **make this city [Makkah] secure** and keep me and my sons away from worshipping idols. My Lord, indeed they have led astray many among the people. So whoever follows me - then he is of me; and whoever disobeys me - indeed, You are [yet] Forgiving and Merciful. Our Lord, **I have settled some of my descendants in an uncultivated valley near Your sacred House**, our Lord, that they may establish prayer. So make hearts among the people incline toward them and provide for them from the fruits that they might be grateful.

> [Jami Tirmizi](https://sunnah.com/urn/734660) and (variant) [Sahih Muslim, Book of Virtue](https://sunnah.com/muslim/43/1) :
>
> قال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ ان الله اصطفى من ولد **ابراهيم** **اسماعيل** واصطفى من ولد اسماعيل بني كنانة واصطفى من بني كنانة قريشا واصطفى من قريش بني هاشم واصطفاني من بني هاشم ‏
>
> The Messenger of Allah said:  "Indeed Allah has chosen **Ishmael from the children of Abraham**, and He chose Banu Kinanah from the children of Ishmael, and He chose the Quraish from Banu Kinanah, and He chose Banu Hashim from Quraish, and He chose me from Banu Hashim."

You can find a detailed accounts of this in e.g  the Seerah of Ibn Kathir [here](https://archive.org/stream/TheLifeOfTheProphetMuhammad-EnglishTranslationOfIbnKathirsAlSira/TheLifeOfTheProphetMuhammad-EnglishTranslationOfIbnKathirsAlSiraAlNabawiyyaVolume1#page/n61/mode/2up).

---

Regarding the origin of the name *Allah*. Its a special form of *ilah* (god) and is cognate to the Hebrew [*Elohim*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H430&t=KJV) which is from [*Eloah*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H433&t=KJV) (also see Aramaic [*Elah*](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?strongs=H426&t=KJV)) which is thought to be derived from the semitic name [*EL*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_(deity)) (as in Gabri**EL** and Ishma**EL**), all forms occur in the Torah\Tanakh to refer to God.

Examples of their usage in the Tanakh\Old Testament:

> *Bereshit, bara **elohim**, et hashamayim, ve'et ha'aretz*
>
> In the beginning **God** created the heaven and the earth.
>
> <sup>— [Genesis 1:1](http://biblehub.com/text/genesis/1-1.htm)</sup>

...

> *Vayishman yeshurun vayiv'at, shamanta avita kasita; vayittosh **eloah** asahu, vaynabbel tzur yeshu'ato*
>
> And Jeshurun became fat and rebelled; you grew fat, thick and rotund;
> [Israel] forsook the **God** Who made them, and spurned the [Mighty]
> Rock of their salvation.
>
> <sup>— [Deuteronomy 32:15](http://biblehub.com/text/deuteronomy/32-15.htm)</sup>

...

> *bishnat ẖada lekhovresh malkaˈ kovresh malkaˈ sam teˈem bet-ˈ**elaha** virushelem*
>
> In the first year of Cyrus the king the same Cyrus the king made a
> decree concerning the house of **God** at Jerusalem.
>
> <sup>— [Ezra 6:3](http://biblehub.com/text/ezra/6-3.htm)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Arabs knew Allah before Islam. Their problem was that they didn't worship Him alone.

Quran explains this in many places, for example:

> And if you should ask them, "Who has created the heavens and the
>   earth?" they would surely say, "They were created by the Exalted in
>   Might, the Knowing." 43-9

Also

> Unquestionably, for Allah is the pure religion. And those who take
>   protectors besides Him [say], "We only worship them that they may
>   bring us nearer to **Allah** in position." Indeed, Allah will judge
>   between them concerning that over which they differ. Indeed, Allah
>   does not guide he who is a liar and [confirmed] disbeliever. 39-3

As you mentioned also, Arabs before Islam had names like Abdu-Allah, (Allah's servant).

Comment: With regard, how Arabs familiar with Allah before Islam? And what they known about Allah, before Islam? And what about Idol and idolatry? As their religion was Idolatry, who was believe Idol, what place did Allah have for them?

Comment: Yes they worshipped idols, but remember they had followers of Abraham, christians, and from the jews amongest them.
For them Allah was The creator, and they thought they would become nearer by worshipping the idols.

Comment: Is Allah name common within Christians and Jews? What is the God name within this religions?

Comment: In Arabic Christians and Jews use Allah. In Hebrew  used to call Him YaHwe, or in the past YAHWA (ya Hwa- meaning O He). In the bible  you can find it as Ela, or as in the Movie of Jesus, Ala.

Answer (score 0):

There were different types of Arabs before islam majority were pagans but some where christians or jews but all arabs used the word Allah for god .there are archaeological evidences showing rings worned by arab christians with the word Allah inscribed on it