# Regarding with the parents of Prophet Muhammad?

Tags: prophet-muhammad

My question is very simple in my last question someone replied to me that the parents of Prophet Muhammad were non muslim . How could that be correct ! In fact their father's name was Abdullah . My mother told me that only his uncle ( Abu talib is jahanami( In hell) ) .And tell me one more thing I don't think that Prophet Muhammad created the Salah because there were some famous Prophets like Moosa -al hai salaam , ( Moses  ) . Haven't they offered Salah ?

Comment: Relevant post https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43851/what-was-the-meaning-of-the-name-allah-before-islam and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39804/in-which-direction-did-noah-and-adam-pray

Comment: The parents of our Prophet as well as his uncle Abu Talib and his grand father Abdul Muttalib never worshipped idols, they were all monotheists.

Comment: ['Abdullah ibn Ubayy ibn Salool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd-Allah_ibn_Ubayy) was both an idol worshiper before the Prophet migrated to Medina and a hypocrite after _hijra_, and his name was 'Abdullah, too. Please provide your reference that one called 'Abdullah cannot be a disbeliever. It was the Prophet that said [his father is in hellfire](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/1/408), and that his uncle [Abu Talib is also in hellfire](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/78/232).

Comment: Where is it there in the Qu'ran that he said that his father was in helfire ?

I know that his uncle is in Hell  I don't know about his father ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes true, his name was Abdullah which means "worshiper of God", that is because before prophet Muhammad came, people knew that there was a God, however his people were worshiping statues as a way to be nearer to the God.

Other people were christian, others knew that there is only one God.

You see after Jesus, some people stayed following the true way, others (majority) went through wrong ways.

Then you are saying that parents of prophet are in hell??

well, they might, they might not, because they both died before Muhammad became a prophet so they were not told about the true way.

Any way, wife of prophet Lut is, son of prophet Noah is, why it is a big deal?

Regarding the second part of your question, "Salah" is a practice, and practices were different between prophets (different steps, different counts, different hows).